# What do I need from visual studio to run application without visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, .net-assembly, dependency-management

I'm not very familiar with VS.

I have inherited a set of VS projects and I can run the one I'm currently interested in within Visual Studio.

But, when I take the generated .exe file and try to run it from the cmd line, I get an error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly ...
```

So how do I find this missing assembly, where should I put it (ie. in the same folder as the .exe)?

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Which assembly is missing ? ideally should present in the same folder if not system assembly.

Comment: Run it from vs in release mode and go to the bin/release folder of the project. The dll's and exe are in there. Its also where visual studio runs it from so if it works within vs. it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm presuming you have moved the file from the build folder so I would copy all the dlls in the folder where your exe was built to your new location.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your machine is missing some asset or libraries (*.dll). i thinks right direction is trying to check the source code, try to compile the source code on your machine to see what is happening on your machine, which kind of file or library are missing. if you dont want to install visual studio, you can try SharpDevelop IDE here http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/Default.aspx